# Appstore connect rejects update (flutter app) because of unsupported minimum OS Version in info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store-connect, flutter-ios

I want to upload an appbuild from my flutterapp into the appstore connect. I analyzed and archived it. After analyzing it seemingly successfully, the build gets uploaded into the appstore connect.
When almost done, I get the following error message:
`Invalid Bundle. The bundle Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist.`

[image]

This is my Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>Dutch</string>
        <string>ko</string>
        <string>Spanish</string>
        <string>it</string>
        <string>ja</string>
        <string>fr</string>
        <string>en</string>
        <string>de</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Horizonpedia</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>https</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>catalogscanner.horizonpedia.com</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
    <string>redacted</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I tried changing the target Version for my project to iOS 9.0 but that didnt fix it.
Any idea what I could try next?

Comment: Is this flutter?

Comment: yes. I think I should edit the question regardingto that

Comment: OK so see for example https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58200